# adding legend after inserting lines using insertshape function in matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, imshow

My code looks like this:

```
p = imread('C.png');
p1 = im2double(p);
RG = insertShape(p1, 'Filledcircle', pos1, 'LineWidth', 10,'Color','blue','Opacity',1);
RG = insertShape(RG, 'Line', {line1,line2},'Color',{0 1 0;0 1 1});
hc = imshow(RG);
legend(hc,'line1','line2');
legend('show');
```

I am taking my x and y coordinates from the circles i have inserted using image viewer app , is it not the right way to get the coordinates to coonect them together.

Comment: I am not sure but I think `legend` works only with `plot`, `scatter` etc. Give a  try to write a string on the required place using [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) as a replacement for `legend`!

Comment: In other words, `legend` might need an `axes` object to associate with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertShape` modifies the image's RGB data directly and does not generate graphics objects for the shapes that are inserted. Because of this, there are no graphics handles for `legend` to display (see also: [the valid object types for `legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#inputarg_obj)

As one workaround, you can generate a dummy line series for each of your shapes. Because `NaN` values are not rendered visually by MATLAB, they can be used to create a Line Object that's not displayed on your axes.

For example:

```
% Read sample image
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(RGB);

% Add some annotations
dim1 = [0.3 0.7 0.2 0.2];
annotation('rectangle', dim1, 'Color', 'red')
dim2 = [0.6 0.5 0.1 0.1];
annotation('rectangle', dim2, 'Color', 'blue')
x1 = [0.5 0.6];
y1 = [0.7 0.5]; 
annotation('line', x1, y1, 'Color', 'green', 'LineWidth', 2)
x2 = [0.5 0.7];
y2 = [0.9 0.6];
annotation('line', x2, y2, 'Color', 'magenta', 'LineWidth', 2)

% ============== EVERYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE IS SPECIFIC TO MY EXAMPLE, IGNORE IT

% Plot dummy lineseries for legend
% Specify 'DisplayName' for legend, can also be done manually in legend call
hold on
tmp(1) = plot(NaN, 'Color', 'green', 'LineWidth', 2, 'DisplayName', 'Green Line');
tmp(2) = plot(NaN, 'Color', 'magenta', 'LineWidth', 2, 'DisplayName', 'Magenta Line');
hold off

% Display legend
legend(tmp)
```

Which produces the following:

[image: yay]

Comment: thanks for your comment, i need to connect 2 circles by 2 lines and i have the x and y coordinates for both , how do i do it using annotation:    line1 = [494,286,561,235];   line 2 = [580,228,672,197]    and i tried it an doesn't seem to work for me using annotation

Comment: @Kira you don't need to use `annotation`. Use `insertShape` like you are already doing. I only used `annotation` because I don't have the Computer Vision Toolbox.

Comment: i tried that too still doesn't display the legend if i do imshow before legend , but if i call the legend function in the end then only the legend is displayed with no image

Comment: @Kira then update your question with the code that isn't working. I am calling `legend` after `imshow` in my example without any issue.

Comment: it seems to work now but im using plot function instead of annotation although my x and y coordinates are  a complete mismatch , i am unable to connect the circles, will update the code now, thanks

Comment: @Kira why are you trying to plot lines? All you have to do is plot one `NaN` for each desired legend entry. **Leave your annotation like you had it before**

Comment: if i do that insertshape for lines doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Kira you've completely changed your question. Read the documentation for `insertshape`, it tells you how to define the line segments. Dimensions are *pixel values*